# c++, Why is my array empty?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I am new to c++, so this is probably going to be very obvious.

In my program, I am making an array, writing it to a binary file, then reading it into another array and printing it.

I can't seem to read from the binary file to the new array. When I try to print out the new array, it becomes clear that it is empty. Can you help me see what I've done wrong?

```
int main(){
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    int* array = new int[N*N];

    for(int row = 0; row < N; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < N; column++){
            array[row*N + column] = (row + column)%10;
            cout << array[row*N + column];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------

    ofstream out("array.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
    out.write((char*)array,N*N*sizeof(int));

    //------------------------------------------------------

    int* altArray = new int[N*N];
    ifstream in;
    in.open("array.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

    in.read((char*)altArray, N*N*sizeof(int));

    //-----------------------------------------------------

    cout << "From Binary File\n";

    for(int row = 0; row < N; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < N; column++){
            cout << altArray[row*N + column];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------

    delete []array;
    delete []altArray;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try flushing/closing the outstream before attempting to read the file. I suspect buffering may be your problem.

Comment: **How** do you notice it's _'empty'_? I don't get what you're asking??

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of `N`, the array contents might be still in the ouput buffer and not flushed. You must either flush the buffers to disk or close the file, e.g.

```
out.close();
```

Then, you should see the contents of the array, when reading back again.

Answer (score 1):

```
out.write((char*)array, N*N*sizeof(int));
// ...
in.read((char*)altArray, N*N*sizeof(int));
```

File streams maintain their data though buffering. The output sequence apparently was not flushed out of the buffer before the data was read into the program. You need to flush the output stream first:

```
out << std::flush;
```

this can also be done by closing the file if the file stream is no longer needed..

Another option is that you can `tie()` the streams together so that the input sequence is synchronized whenever a read is performed:

```
in.tie(&out);
```